# Run command in EC2 using Fabric

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, passwords, fabric

I am learning Fabric in Python to run commands in instances EC2 (AWS) from remote. Here is my simple script:

```
from fabric.api import *

env.hosts = ['ec2-**-****-**-**.compute.amazonaws.com']
env.user = 'ubuntu'
env.key_filename = 'myKey.pem'

def update():
    run('mkdir Hello')
```

However, when I run the script, `fab update`, I get this messages:

```
Executing task 'update'
run: mkdir Hello
Login password for 'ubuntu':
```

At this point I do not know which password I need to enter!. Is there some way to skip password request?

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: in case, check the permissions of myKey.pem (it should work with `chmod 400 myKey.pem`) and check also that the key is properly configured in the ec2 instance.

Comment: Can you access EC2 instance manually via ssh command? Did you try to set `~/.ssh/config`? Are username, path to private key or authorized_key on remote server set correctly?